# Workout how many columns are in the CSV?

Tags: python, django

I'm just playing around with classes and methods as a learning exercise.

The method I'm struggling to create is a new one that works out how many columns are in a CSV.

**How can I workout how many columns are in a CSV?**

My Class so far, *(happy for you to point out and mistakes in this is also)*.

```
import csv

class CSV:


    def __init__(self, file=None):
        self.file = file

    def read_file(self):
        data = []
        file_read = csv.reader(self.file)
        for row in file_read:
            data.append(row)
        return data

    def get_row_count(self):
        return len(self.read_file())

    def get_data(self, rows=1):
        data = self.read_file()

        return data[:rows]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way I can think of is just to grab the first row in your csv and return the length of it. CSV files cannot actually have their length read, so first you must put the rows in an array. I will call your `read_file()` function to get the data **as an array** and take the first row:

```
def get_column_number(self):
    new_data = self.read_file()
    return len(new_data[0])
```

Comment: That will give you the number of characters, not the number of columns.

Comment: no, it will get you the number of columns...a csv is 2dimensional...`len(file)` will give you how many rows, `len(file[0])` will give you how many columns, and if you really do want the amount of characters in a specific column, use `len(file[row,column])`

Comment: haha yes, that is my bad...you do need to separate it like that

Comment: @RyanSaxe: I was about to comment that you can't even do `len(file_read[0])` but I see you've rewritten your code. So at least now your answer should work. But it reads in the whole file unnecessarily. If you're only going to get the length of the first row anyway, why not just stop after reading the first row?

Comment: This is definitely true! I was in the middle of an edit where I use his previous `read_file()` function since that will grab the data, but taking just the first row would definitely be quicker

Comment: @RyanSaxe: You're right, I missed that you were using OP's read method. I've deleted my erroneous comments.

Answer (score 4):

If you're sure all the rows will have the same number of columns, then you can simply read the first row and take its length:

```
self.file_read = csv.reader(self.file)
self.columns = len(self.file_read.next())
```

Note that `.next()` consumes one row.  (If using Python 3, you would do `len(next(self.file_read))`.

Comment: you actually can't take `len()` of a csv file...you need to put it in an array first

Comment: @RyanSaxe: I'm not taking `len()` of a CSV file.

Comment: @RyanSaxe: Look carefully, I'm not taking the length of that.

Comment: Very clever!! You're using `.next()` to grab the first row! Also will make his life easier if they are column names because he now has them! +1